# Arduino Pulse Generation

Tags: arduino, integrated-circuit, timer, pulse

I have a Arduino sketch that can rotate 2 stepper motor using a stepper driver that has 256 micro stepping.

I used Arduino MEGA timer 1 and timer 3 with fCLK/8 prescaller for generating step pulse for each stepper driver.

In my code I used ISR for toggle the pin state as below:

```
ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) { //top motor
  PORTL ^= 1;

}

ISR(TIMER3_COMPA_vect) { //bot motor
  PORTL ^= (1 << 4);
}
```

This ISR use program time while toggling the pin state (it takes few uS and if timer interrupts become higher frequency, it take more time from main program). It is a problem for Serial communication of the Arduino.

I want to generate pulse with different frequencies between about 100Hz to 67kHz.

Is there any other way to generate a pulse using Arduino?
Is there any dedicated programmable pulse generator IC for my application? It should has a communication interface to mealtime frequency change.

Comment: hmm so you dont want your stepper to be controlled by uno?

Comment: @MituRaj Im using a MEGA. I need to change pulse frequency using MEAG. Dedicated IC should be a interface that can communicate with Arduino.

Comment: And how do you want to change the pulse frequency? By a knob? Other IC/computer?
Also, with pulse frequency, do you mean a square wave with 50% duty cycle or how should this pulse look like?
Can you post the complete program?

Comment: @Swedgin pulse should be 50% duty cycle square wave. I want to change frequency using command through Ardunio by Serial communication interface .

Comment: Note that you don't need 2 timers. You also can use just one in PWM mode or playing with the (out top of my head) `OCCRA` and `OCCRB` registers.